# How to generate normal random variates >= zero in Scipy efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to generate normal random variates that are above zero with Scipy or Numpy. How do I do it efficiently?

Presently, I had used `scipy.stats.norm.rvs()` to generate the normal random variates. Thereafter, used `numpy.where()` to locate the random variates that are less than zero. Finally use a while-loop to regenerate the normal random variates, one element at a time, until a value more than zero is obtained. A sample code is shown below. However, this approach is pretty slow, especially for a large multi-dimensional array and this procedure has to be iterated.

Is there a function in Scipy that already does this that I can use? Or, what is the more efficient way to what I need?

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

numbers = norm.rvs( loc=1, scale=0.475, size=1000 ).reshape(2,5,100)
print( f'numbers = {numbers}' )
locations = np.where( numbers<0 )
print( f'locations = {locations}' )

for x,y,z in zip( *locations ):
    while True:
        g = norm.rvs( loc=1, scale=0.475, size=1 )
        if g >= 0.0:
            numbers[x,y,z] = g[0]
            break

location = np.where( numbers<0 )
print( f'location = {location}' )
```

Comment: @sascha Agree. But an issue with this approach is that a larger sampling size may not be sufficiently large. If one uses an even larger sampling size, more compute resource is used. Competition between not having a large enough sampling size and using too much compute resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the distribution [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html), the truncated normal distribution.  In the following example, `loc` and `scale` give the mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution, and `left` and `right` give the window that you are interested in.  In this case, we want positive values, so we use `left = 0` and `right = np.inf`.

```
In [59]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [60]: from scipy.stats import truncnorm

In [61]: loc = 1

In [62]: scale = 0.475

In [63]: left = 0

In [64]: right = np.inf
```

These formulas convert the above parameters to the form expected by `truncnorm`.

```
In [65]: a = (left - loc)/scale

In [66]: b = (right - loc)/scale
```

Generate a large sample, and plot the histogram.

```
In [67]: z = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc, scale, size=100000)

In [68]: plt.hist(z, bins=100)
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: I have tried to apply `truncnorm` for 3D array but seem to have issues. Can you advice me on what I had done wrong? [new question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66622761/5722359)