# How to speed up scipy.stats.truncnorm for 3D array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For 1D array, I found that the generation of `rsv` by `truncnorm` is at least 1 order of magnitude faster than using `norm` and `np.where`. The 1D test code is shown below. Timing result is:

```
atotal time= 0.0018085979972966015  # norm and np.where
btotal time= 0.0006862149748485535  # truncnorm
```

For 3D array, I found `truncnorm` very much slower than using `norm` and `np.where`. The 3D test code is shown below. Timing result is:

```
atotal time= 0.29120742401573807  # norm and np.where
btotal time= 34.368199132964946  # truncnorm
```

**Question:**

1. In the 3D comparison, why is `truncnorm` 2 orders of magnitude slower than `norm` and `np.where`? How can I speed things up for this 3D `truncnorm`? The 1D Comparison result showed that `truncnorm` should be faster than the `norm` and `np.where` approach.

Essentially, I am trying to use `truncnorm` for 3D arrays. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Appreciate advice to overcoming my issue.

[image: 1D Comparison]

[image: 3D Comparison]

**Test Code for 1D Comparison:**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng, SeedSequence
from scipy.stats import norm, truncnorm
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p=1000

loc = 3
scale = 1.475

# Approach A: scipy.stats.norm
astart=time.perf_counter()
sq1 = np.random.SeedSequence(1234567890)
rng = default_rng( sq1 )
anumbers = norm.rvs( loc=loc, scale=scale, size=p, random_state=rng )
al = np.where( anumbers<0 )
for x in al[0]:
    while True:
        g = norm.rvs( loc=loc, scale=scale, size=1, random_state=rng )
        if g >= 0.0:
            anumbers[x] = g[0]
            break
al = np.where( anumbers<0 )
aend=time.perf_counter()
print( f'anumbers={anumbers} size={anumbers.size} mean={anumbers.mean()} std={anumbers.std()}' )
print( f'al = {al} {al[0].size}' )

# Approach B: scipy.stats.truncnorm
bstart=time.perf_counter()
sq1 = np.random.SeedSequence(1234567890)
rng = default_rng( sq1 )
left = 0
right = np.inf
a = ( left - loc ) / scale
b = ( right - loc ) / scale
bnumbers = truncnorm.rvs( a, b, loc=loc, scale=scale, size=p, random_state=rng )
bl = np.where( bnumbers<0 )
bend=time.perf_counter()
print( f'\nbnumbers={bnumbers} size={bnumbers.size} mean={bnumbers.mean()} std={bnumbers.std()}' )
print( f'bl = {bl} {bl[0].size}' )

print()
print( f'atotal time= {aend-astart}' )
print( f'btotal time= {bend-bstart}' )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_title('1D Comparison')
ax.hist( anumbers, bins=100, label='scipy.stats.norm and numpy.where methods', alpha=0.6 )
ax.hist( bnumbers, bins=100, label='scipy.stats.trucnorm', alpha=0.6  )
ax.legend( loc='upper right' )
plt.show()
```

**Test Code for 3D Comparison:**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng, SeedSequence
from scipy.stats import norm, truncnorm
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

it=15
s=18
p=1000
pshape=(it,s,p)
size = it*s*p

mu = 3
sigma = 1.475
loc = np.empty( p, dtype=np.int64 )
loc[:]=mu
loc3d = np.broadcast_to( loc[None,None,:], pshape )
scale = np.empty( p, dtype=np.float64 )
scale[:]=sigma
scale3d = np.broadcast_to( scale[None,None,:], pshape )
print( f'loc3d={loc3d} shape={loc3d.shape}' )
print( f'\nscale3d={scale3d} shape={scale3d.shape}' )

# Approach A: scipy.stats.norm
astart=time.perf_counter()
sq1 = np.random.SeedSequence(1234567890)
rng = default_rng( sq1 )
anumbers3d = norm.rvs( loc=loc3d, scale=scale3d, size=pshape, random_state=rng )
al3d = np.where( anumbers3d<0 )
for x,y,z in zip(*al3d):
    while True:
        g = norm.rvs( loc=loc3d[x,y,z], scale=scale3d[x,y,z], size=1, random_state=rng )
        if g >= 0.0:
            anumbers3d[x,y,z] = g[0]
            break
al3d = np.where( anumbers3d<0 )
aend=time.perf_counter()
#print( f'anumbers3d={anumbers3d} size={anumbers3d.size} mean={anumbers3d.mean()} std={anumbers3d.std()}' )
print( f'al3d = {al3d} {al3d[0].size}' )


## Approach B: scipy.stats.truncnorm
bstart=time.perf_counter()
sq1 = np.random.SeedSequence(1234567890)
rng = default_rng( sq1 )
left = np.zeros( p, dtype=np.int64 )
left3d = np.broadcast_to( left[None,None,:], pshape )
right = np.empty( p, dtype=np.float64 )
right[:] = np.inf
right3d = np.broadcast_to( right[None,None,:], pshape )
a3d = ( left3d - loc3d ) / scale3d
b3d = ( right3d - loc3d ) / scale3d
bnumbers3d = truncnorm.rvs( a3d, b3d, loc=loc3d, scale=scale3d, size=pshape, random_state=rng )
bl3d = np.where( bnumbers3d<0 )
bend=time.perf_counter()
#print( f'\nbnumbers3d={bnumbers3d} size={bnumbers3d.size} mean={bnumbers3d.mean()} std={bnumbers3d.std()}' )
print( f'bl3d = {bl3d} {bl3d[0].size}' )

print( f'\natotal time= {aend-astart}' )
print( f'btotal time= {bend-bstart}' )

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('3D Comparison', fontsize=18)
ax[0].set_title('scipy.stats.norm and numpy.where')
ax[1].set_title('scipy.stats.truncnorm')
for x in anumbers3d:
    for y in x:
        ax[0].hist( y, bins=100, label='anumbers3d', alpha=0.6 )
for x in bnumbers3d:
    for y in x:
        ax[1].hist( y, bins=100, label='bnumbers3d', alpha=0.6 )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`truncnorm.rvs` is so much slower in the 3d case because the parameters you feed in for `a`, `b`, `loc`, and `scale` are arrays the same shape as your desired output. So, for the numbers you show, you need to create four 270,000-element arrays, which will clog your memory (which on its own slows the code), *plus* scipy needs to check every element of the arrays for every element it generates. It's perfectly fine to use scalars for those parameters, as you do in the 1d case; the shape of the output array is determined by the `size` argument.

A side note: because of this checking-every-element behavior, you won't get the same output using arrays vs. using scalars in the function call, even if you use the same `SeedSequence`.

Comment: How can I speed things up for this 3D truncnorm? Can you make the changes to my 3D script to show me what you mean? I don't quite understand your answer. Assume that RAM size isn't an issue. Do note that the dimensions of the inputs to the functions are 15x 8x1000.

Comment: If your explanation is true, then why does `norm.rvs`, which uses 3d arrays as input, not encounter the same issue. Also, the inputs cannot be a scalar for this 3D calculation.

Comment: @SunBear The inputs most certainly can be scalars. If you define `left`, `right`, `a`, and `b` as you do in your 1d example, then call `truncnorm.rvs` as `bnumbers3d = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc = mu, scale = sigma, size = pshape, random_state = rng)`, it will work fine. If you look at your arrays `a3d`, `b3d`, `loc3d`, and `scale3d`, note that every element is the same. This is a tremendous waste of space. And I suspect `norm.rvs` doesn't suffer from the same issue because it's much simpler mathematically. Also, the input array dimensions are 15x18x1000, as define in the tuple `pshape`.

Comment: Also, for future reference, if you _do_ want to define an array of all the same value, the preferred way is to use `numpy`'s `ones()` function. For example, you can create your array `loc3d` as: `loc3d = mu*np.ones(pshape)` @SunBear

Comment: In my real scenario, mu and sigma are not a scalar as their elements have different values. I simplified their expression to use the same number in the 3D example. Apologies for not clarifying. So finally, truncnorm inputs are non scalar and has size of 15x18x1000.

Comment: Ah, apologies for misunderstanding. `truncnorm` certainly isn't very friendly to changing the mean and variance while keeping the bounds fixed. Approach A may have to be the way to go.

Comment: If you can get the size of your inputs down at all, you can get some more speed out of truncnorm - if you just need, for example, 15 values of mu and 18 values of sigma, with 1000 numbers generated for each combination, you can make your inputs have shape (15,18,1) and keep your output size (15,18,1000), and it will work (np.expand_dims will be your friend in adding the extra dimension to the end: axis = 2). If all 270,000 elements truly need different params, then I don't know.